# Switching from jboss-eap-6.1 to jboss-as-7.1.1.Final not able to deploy my complete database file

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x, hsqldb, jboss6.x

I am using ***HSQLDB*** as database in our project. thus My project need `'mydb.script'` (*original size 7,012 bytes*) file *(which is bundeled in my project)* to connect with the database.

It working fine when I deploy it on ***jboss-eap-6.1*** and takes my Database script file from

```
JBOSS_6_HOME/standalone/deployments/myproject.war/WEB-INF/classes/mydb.script
```

location and the *size of script file is same as original size i.e. 7,012*  bytes.

Now when I am deploying the same project on ***jboss-as-7.1.1.Final*** which takes my script file from

```
JBOSS_7_HOME/modules/sun/jdk/main/service-loader-resources/mydb.script
```

location which is an *incomplete file i.e. size of script file is 1601 bytes* and it not taking my script file from

```
JBOSS_7_HOME/standalone/deployments/myproject.war/WEB-INF/classes/mydb.script
```

path,Java Code To get file path of my script file

***Java Code***

```
DBConnectionManager.class.getClassLoader().getResource("").getFile()
```

Can any one help me out Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Did you placed `mydb.script` in `JBOSS_7_HOME/modules/sun/jdk/main/service-loader-resources`?

If not then you can remove this file and then it will pick it from you project.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I dont want to do it manually Jboss should take care of it.